# How to access topic words only in gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I built LDA model using Gensim and I want to get the topic words only How can I get the words of the topics only no probabilities and no IDs.words only

I tried print_topics() and show_topics() functions in gensim but I can't get clean words !

This is the code I used

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=12, id2word = dictionary, passes = 100, alpha='auto', update_every=5)
x = ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=12, num_words=5)
for i in x:
    print(i[1])
    #print('\n' + str(i))

0.045*تعرض + 0.045*الماضية + 0.045*السنوات + 0.045*وءسرته + 0.045*لءحمد
0.021*مصر + 0.021*الديمقراطية + 0.021*حرية + 0.021*باسم + 0.021*الحكومة
0.068*المواطنة + 0.068*الطاءفية + 0.068*وانهيارات + 0.068*رابطة + 0.005*طبول
0.033*عربية + 0.033*انكسارات + 0.033*رهابيين + 0.033*بحقوق + 0.033*ل
0.007*وحريات + 0.007*ممنهج + 0.007*قواءم + 0.007*الناس + 0.007*دراج
0.116*طبول + 0.116*الوطنية + 0.060*يكتب + 0.060*مصر + 0.005*عربية
0.064*قيم + 0.064*وهن + 0.064*عربيا + 0.064*والتعددية + 0.064*الديمقراطية
0.036*تضامنا + 0.036*الشخصية + 0.036*مع + 0.036*التفتيش + 0.036*الءخلاق
0.052*تضامنا + 0.052*كل + 0.052*محمد + 0.052*الخلوق + 0.052*مظلوم
0.034*بمواطنين + 0.034*رهابية + 0.034*لم + 0.034*عليهم + 0.034*يثبت
0.035*مع + 0.035*ومستشار + 0.035*يستعيدا + 0.035*ءرهقهما + 0.035*حريتهما
0.064*للقمع + 0.064*قريبة + 0.064*لا + 0.064*نهاية + 0.064*مصر
```

I tried show_topics and it gave the same output

```
y = np.array(ldamodel.show_topics(num_topics=12, num_words=5))
for i in y[:,1]:
    #if i != '%d':
    #print([str(word) for word in i])
    print(i)
```

If I have the topic ID how can I access its words and other informations

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the below code snippet should give you a list of tuples containing the each topic(tp) and corresponding list of words(wd) in that topic

```
x=ldamodel.show_topics(num_topics=12, num_words=5,formatted=False)
topics_words = [(tp[0], [wd[0] for wd in tp[1]]) for tp in x]

#Below Code Prints Topics and Words
for topic,words in topics_words:
    print(str(topic)+ "::"+ str(words))
print()

#Below Code Prints Only Words 
for topic,words in topics_words:
    print(" ".join(words))
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answer was giving a string with weights associated with each word. But if you want to get each word in a topic separately for further work. Then you can try this. Here topic no is the key to the dictionary and the value is a single string containing all words in that topic separated by space

```
x=ldamodel.show_topics()

twords={}
for topic,word in x:
    twords[topic]=re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]+', '', word)
print(twords)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your model is called `ldamodel`:

```
my_dict = {'Topic_' + str(i): [token for token, score in ldamodel.show_topic(i, topn=10)] for i in range(0, ldamodel.num_topics)}
```

And we get (for 2 topics):

```
print(my_dict)

{'Topic_0': ['excel',
  'data',
  'learn',
  'feedback',
  'coaching',
  'tips',
  'digital',
  'use',
  'team',
  'people'],
 'Topic_1': ['leadership',
  'decisions',
  'business',
  'agile',
  'people',
  'change',
  'global',
  'data',
  'team',
  'leaders']}
```

Or `my_dict['Topic_0']` and we get:

```
['excel',
 'data',
 'learn',
 'feedback',
 'coaching',
 'tips',
 'digital',
 'use',
 'team',
 'people']
```

Answer (score 1):

show_topic(*<id of topic target>*, *<quantity of relevant words you want>*) return you a list of pairs (word, probability). See [gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.show_topic) for details

from operator import itemgetter(*<idx>*) that will help you take the first element (if 0, or any other idx position) from a iterable (like the tuples above)

Suppose you model var is **lda_model** and you have **5 topics** and **10 words** wanted from all of them (*topn=10* param in show_topic as default):

```
from operator import itemgetter

for n in range(5):
    print(list(map(itemgetter(0), [*lda_model.show_topic(n)])))
```

I'd iterated by range but enumerate topics or getting its topicno is a better practice

Answer (score 0):

You could use **get_topic_terms()** in gensim instead of print_topics() and show_topics() functions.

Assume you have the following 2 variables: **id2word** and **lda_model**, where they were defined as follows:

```
corpus_words = [['term1', 'term_2'], ['term3', 'term4']]
id2word = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(corpus_words)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in corpus_words]
lda_model = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, num_topics=2)
```

By calling **get_topic_terms()**:

```
[ lda_model.get_topic_terms(tid, topn=3)] for tid in range(2) ]
```

you got 3 words' ids and their scores for each of the 2 topics.

Then, the following would be what are needed:

```
[ [(id2word[wid], s) for (wid, s) in lda_model.get_topic_terms(tid, topn=3)] for tid in range(2)]

[[('term1', 0.32463402), ('term_2', 0.3211307), ('term4', 0.18077125)], 
 [('term3', 0.3250474), ('term4', 0.31788236), ('term_2', 0.18025273)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern gensim there is **no need to parse or use token-id maps**. The one-liner is

```py
list(w for w,_ in lda.show_topic(topicid=7,topn=10))
```

with the use of [`show_topc`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.show_topic), which gives `topn` words per `topicid`, like:

```
['change',
 'https',
 '#leadershipofchange',
 '#changemanagement',
 '#cx',
 'leadership',
 'management',
 'customer',
 'experience',
 '#customerexperience']
```

Note: Tested under `gensim==4.3`.